# error: 'class cv::String' has no member named 'data'

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm stuck up with writing in the xml file,my  cpp code looks like

```
void Player::saveConfig()
{
  char file_xml[200];
  sprintf(file_xml,"./config/%s.VehicleCounting.xml",filename.data()); //here is the error
  CvFileStorage* fs = cvOpenFileStorage(file_xml, 0, CV_STORAGE_WRITE);

  cvWriteInt(fs, "showOutput", showOutput);
  cvWriteInt(fs, "showAB", showAB);
  cvWriteInt(fs,"module",FAV1::module);
  cvWriteInt(fs, "fav1_use_roi", FAV1::use_roi);
  cvWriteInt(fs, "fav1_roi_defined", FAV1::roi_defined);
  cvWriteInt(fs, "fav1_roi_x0", FAV1::roi_x0);
  cvWriteInt(fs, "fav1_roi_y0", FAV1::roi_y0);
  cvWriteInt(fs, "fav1_roi_x1", FAV1::roi_x1);
  cvWriteInt(fs, "fav1_roi_y1", FAV1::roi_y1);
 cvReleaseFileStorage(&fs);
}
```

and the class declaration of my header file is given below

```
class Player : public QThread
{    Q_OBJECT
 private:
    bool stop;
    QMutex mutex;
    QWaitCondition condition;
    Mat frame;
    int frameRate;
    VideoCapture *capture;
    Mat RGBframe;
    QImage img;
    BlobTracking* blobTracking;
    IBGS *bgs;

     bool firstTime;
     bool showOutput;
     int key;
     cv::Mat img_input;
     cvb::CvTracks tracks;
     std::map<cvb::CvID, std::vector<CvPoint2D64f> > points;
     LaneOrientation LaneOrientation;
     std::map<cvb::CvID, VehiclePosition> positions;
     long countAB;
     long countBA;
     int img_w;
     int img_h;
     int showAB;


     VehiclePosition getVehiclePosition(const CvPoint2D64f centroid);
      void saveConfig();
      void loadConfig();

 signals:
 //Signal to output frame to be displayed
      void processedImage(const QImage &image);

 protected:
     void run();
     void msleep(int ms);
 public:
    //Constructor
    Player(QObject *parent = 0);
    //Destructor
    ~Player();
    //Load a video from memory
    bool loadVideo(string filename);
    //Play the video
    void Play();
    //Stop the video
    void Stop();
    //check if the player has been stopped
    bool isStopped() const;
    //set video properties
    void setCurrentFrame( int frameNumber);
    //Get video properties
    double getFrameRate();
    double getCurrentFrame();
    double getNumberOfFrames();

     void setInput(const cv::Mat &i);
     void setTracks(const cvb::CvTracks &t);
     void process();
     String filename;
};
```

please help me out in debugging the errors..I am using opencv3 with qt.I'll be grateful.Thanks in adavance

Comment: (1) Please always read your error message carefully and check the documentation of the relevant classes. (2) Consider accepting an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void process();
String filename;
```

Should be

```
void process();
string filename;
```

Comment: Thank you:) it worked..... but could you please tell me what was the reason for that error?

Comment: cv lib has class `cv::String` but it is not the same as `std::string`. And `cv::String` has no member named 'data' but `std::string` has.